# ERROR: Element Not Found works well in Selenium IDE but not in Selenium RC. getting error

Tags: selenium-rc

this is my script. while clicking a link using its xpath not working & throws an error 'ERROR element not found' but works well in Selenium IDE.

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class testGoogle extends SeleneseTestCase {
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.google.co.in/");
    selenium.start();
    selenium.windowFocus();
    selenium.windowMaximize();
}

@Test
public void testUntitled() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("http://www.google.co.in/");
    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    assertEquals("Google", selenium.getTitle());
    selenium.click("name=q");
    selenium.type("name=q", "Software Testing");
    selenium.click("name=btnK");
    selenium.click("//html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li[2]/div/h3/a");  // ERROR: Element Not Found

    selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    selenium.stop();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can detect link as selenium.click("link=xyz") instead of xpath

Answer (score 0):

The script is absolutely right. But the problem is that it is running very fast. When you start the script all the elements are not fully loaded. So add

**selenium.setSpeed("1000");**

as the very first line in function **testUntitled()**. Your script will run fine.

Cheers,
Amit Shakya

Answer (score 0):

Just add "xpath=" before the path like this

```
xpath=/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ol/li[2]/div/h3/a
```

it will work faced this problem earlier..

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the issue - "Element not found" in Selenium RC.

Using `selenium.setSpeed("1000")` worked.